# Basic expression Antlr4 grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to write a basic grammar that starts with **'{'** and ends with **'}'**.
It has **'IF'** and **'Else'** only. And some basic expressions like *a = (arithmetic operation).* There is no need for variable initialisation and declaration check. Can someone guide me, I am writing grammar, but it is not working properly. I am writing code below of my grammar.

```
prog: stat_block+ EOF;

stat_block
: OBRACE block CBRACE
;

block
: stat*
;

stat: expr
;

expr: expr ('*'|'/') expr
| expr ('+'|'-') expr
| expr ('<'|'<='|'>='|'>'|'=') expr
| expr ( '&&'|'||') expr
| expr '(' exprList? ')'
| IF condition_block  (ELSE stat_block)?
;

exprList : expr (',' expr)* ;

condition_block
: OPAR expr CPAR stat_block
;

IF : 'IF';
ELSE : 'ELSE';
OPAR : '(';
CPAR : ')';
OBRACE : '{';
CBRACE : '}';
ID : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
INT : [0-9]+ ;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

Sample Code for what i am trying to write grammar for

```
{
 IF ( a > 10 && funcName(param) = Found ) {
    b = 10;
 }
 ELSE {
    b=20;
 }
}
```

If statement can be nested. IF some one can provide me with grammar or tell me, what i am doing wrong. that will be huge help. thanks.

Comment: Should `prog` not refer to `stat_block` instead of doing `stat+`? The way you have it now it seems `prog` will not accept a `{` as the first token.

Comment: I pulled down your grammar and sample input.  There are many issues to be addressed before it will parse your sample input.  Is this a homework assignment?  If you post a particular issue your trying to sort through, we might assist you in pointing you toward information to get you "unstuck".  But Pointing out all the issues would essentially amount to posting a new grammar that would just be the answer to your homework.  (More than happy to help with clarifying specific questions about an aspect of ANTLR)

Comment: There are definitely a few problems here. First, you need to fix the lexer portion. Is it `Else` or `else` in the grammar/input? Antlr is case-sensitive. Choose one way or the other. Next, you need to move the `ID` rule below the rules for `IF` and `ELSE`. Otherwise, those keywords are tokenized as `ID`. For the parser rules, you don't even have `expr` deriving an `INT` or `ID`. For the moment, I wouldn't even consider `NEWLINE`, so you should remove references to it in the parser rules. Skip that for now.

Comment: @MikeCargal It is not my homework assignment, Actually i am writing a formula builder for a custom web app. and it needs to parse grammar like i mentioned in my question. I have been scratching my head, trying to write it correctly. And dead line is not allowing me, to read complete Antlr4 book and then write it. What i wrote above is my current understanding of Antlr4. Can you please provide me link to helping material if not complete grammar? I would appreciate it thanks.

Comment: @kaby76  i have updated the grammar. Now i am getting error **mismatched input '\n' expecting '}'** 
and my input is  **{ }**. Can you please review my grammar? and point out the mistakes

Comment: Better, but you need to add `-> skip` to the end of `NEWLINE` for now. Worry about newline termination of expressions later. Also, you need to add `| ID | INT` to the `expr` rule--you have to recognize a number or variable in an expression! This should probably go onto a Stackoverflow chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following changes, I get an error free parse and a parse tree:

1.

```
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
```

You're not using the `NEWLINE` token, so, presumably, you want to hide that token from the parser rules.  `-> skip` is one simple way to accomplish that.

```
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' -> skip;
```

2. 

```
expr
    : expr ('*' | '/') expr
    | expr ('+' | '-') expr
    | expr ('<' | '<=' | '>=' | '>' | '=') expr
    | expr ( '&&' | '||') expr
    | expr '(' exprList? ')'
    | IF condition_block (ELSE stat_block)?
    ;
```

`ID`s and `NUMBER`s should also be considered expressions

```
expr
    : expr ('*' | '/') expr
    | expr ('+' | '-') expr
    | expr ('<' | '<=' | '>=' | '>' | '=') expr
    | expr ( '&&' | '||') expr
    | expr '(' exprList? ')'
    | IF condition_block (ELSE stat_block)? 
    | ID
    | INT
    ;
```

3. 

```
block
: stat*
;

stat: expr
;
```

You haven't accounted for the possibility/requirement of the `;` after an expression

It's not clear you intention. so

To simply say that each expression *may* be followed by a `;`

```
stat: expr ';'?;
```

This would allow for some possible confusion when expressions appear adjacent to one another without a `;`, so consider making it non-optional.

```
stat: expr ';';
```

Many language treat `;` as a expression/statement separator.

```
block: (stat (stat ';')*)?;
```

---

The sum of the changes:

```
grammar Basic
    ;

prog: stat_block+ EOF;

stat_block: OBRACE block CBRACE;

block: (stat (stat ';')*)?;

stat: expr ';'?;

expr
    : expr ('*' | '/') expr
    | expr ('+' | '-') expr
    | expr ('<' | '<=' | '>=' | '>' | '=') expr
    | expr ( '&&' | '||') expr
    | expr '(' exprList? ')'
    | IF condition_block (ELSE stat_block)?
    | ID
    | INT
    ;

exprList: expr (',' expr)*;

condition_block: OPAR expr CPAR stat_block;

IF:      'IF';
ELSE:    'ELSE';
OPAR:    '(';
CPAR:    ')';
OBRACE:  '{';
CBRACE:  '}';
ID:      [a-zA-Z]+;
INT:     [0-9]+;
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
WS:      [ \t]+     -> skip;
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeCargal I learned alot from your answer. I deeply feel indebted to you.